# Space separation between a two-columns ul

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` with two columns (of `li`s). I'm trying to make a visible separation between the two columns, but I can't get it to work. The goal is to make each `li` have a `bottom-color` line, but make those lines separated.

This is what I currently have: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JeluB

HTML

```
<ul id="double">
  <li>asdas</li>
  <li>eee</li>
  <li>iii</li>
  <li>qqqq</li>
  <li>yyyy</li>
  <li>pppp</li>
  <li>p222</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
  width:200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

li{
  line-height: 1.5em;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-right: 2px;
}

#double li  { 
  width: 45%;
}
```

Comment: Can we add a new class to lis?Odd,Even for example?

Comment: @Hbirjand Yes, sure, make all the changes that you think are required :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to apply `border-right` using `:nth-child(odd)`:

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
li {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-right: 2px;
}
#double li {
  width: 45%;
}
#double li:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right: solid 1px #DDDDDD;
}
#double li:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="double">
  <li>asdas</li>
  <li>eee</li>
  <li>iii</li>
  <li>qqqq</li>
  <li>yyyy</li>
  <li>pppp</li>
  <li>p222</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you simply need to give the li elements a margin.
For example

```
li {
    ...
    margin: 0 5px;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

just add `margin-left` and `margin-right` in `li` element. It maybe works.

http://jsfiddle.net/vrajeshdave148/t89yvepj/3/

Answer (score 1):

the property column-gap resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the odd and even classes to the li tags
and I have added the float:right CSS rule to the li tags with even class
and I have added the float:left CSS rule to the li tags with odd class
and I have added a border-bottom to each of the li.even and li.odd separatly 
here is I've achieved

```css
ul{
  width:200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

li{
  line-height: 1.5em;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
 }

#double li  { 
  width:45%;
}
li.odd {border-bottom:3px solid #ccc;float:left;}
li.even {border-bottom:3px solid #ccc;float:right;}
```

```html
<ul id="double">
  <li class="odd">asdas</li>
  <li class="even">eee</li>
  <li class="odd">iii</li>
  <li class="even">qqqq</li>
  <li class="odd">yyyy</li>
  <li class="even">pppp</li>
  <li class="odd">p222</li>
</ul>
```